Can someone explain what is wrong with the train function of this simple linear regression model?
def predict(self, input): 
    return (self.slope*input) + self.bias

def train(self,inputs,targets):
    N = len(inputs)
    predictions = np.array([self.predict(input) for input in inputs])
    errors  = np.array(targets)-predictions

    self.slope += ((np.dot(errors,np.array(inputs)))/N)*self.lr
    self.bias += (np.sum(errors) * self.lr)/N

The output is always of very high magnitude. The learning rate (self.lr) is 0.01.
I have checked the formula everywhere, but I cannot understand what's wrong with what I've written.

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.
